# Некорректно отображается RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Всем привет, я добавил в свой проект RecyclerView, поместил его в LinearLayout c ориентацией "horizontal", но отображается как "verticl"

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:itemCount="3"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_news_card_view" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Чтобы внутренности RecyclerView отображались горизонтально - используйте горизонтальный LayoutManager. LinearLayout тут не поможет

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.